# Should I upgrade my Samsung Galaxy 2 II 4G Epic Touch with Kies or the Simple Upgrade tool to JB?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, updates

I currently have a Samsung Galaxy 2 II 4G Epic Touch and I want to upgrade it to Jelly Bean. After looking at some support pages on Samsung's website, you have two options to install the new version: Kies or Simple Upgrade Tool.

**Which should I use? Kies seems to be easier to use, looks better (not that that matters or anything), doesn't need to be installed (as far as I can tell), has a backup/restore feature, and you don't have to have a full battery or have to mess around with the battery before installing. Is one newer than the other? Does one save more data/settings?**

By the way: what *will* I lose when upgrading? I know it says to back up. How about: favorites, text messages, call history, settings, app data, home screen shortcuts/widget placement, etc. I know I can most likely save notes, photos, voice memos, contacts, emails, etc, but am I starting out with essentially a new phone running Jelly Bean and the basics that I backed up? **How will this compare from Kies to Simple Upgrade Tool?**

Will it keep everything the same, even if I do have to use a backup Samsung recommended with Kies to have in case something went wrong? Or does the backup have a image of the before that I can revert to and be the same as before if something went wrong so I could start from the beginning again?

Comment: **Update:** I forgot to say I'm on Sprint and my phone is the black version (if that matters for model numbers).

Comment: Kies requires a rather long install process :/

Comment: @LiamW Do you know if this is unique to Kies or in general... do you know any other advantages/disadvantages?